# something similar to the Bézout's identity, but with three integers.

Tags: number-theory

There are three positive integers,not all equal. And their greatest common divisor is 1. We can perform this operation on them: choose two not equal integer $a,b(a<b)$ from them, and then $a=a+a,b=b-a$, it seems that we can always produce two (maybe one) integers $1$ from that, is there any proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operation you mention isn't enough. For example, consider the three integers $6,10,15$. Then no pair of those is coprime, while $\gcd(6,10,15) = 1$.

On the other hand, it is fairly easy to write an equivalent of Bezout's identity for any three numbers $a,b,c$ with $\gcd$ $1$. Indeed, if any two of those are coprime, then we can use the usual Bezout identity. Otherwise observe that we can always find two integers $x,y$ such that
$$
d = \gcd(a,b) = ax + by
$$
and that clearly $\gcd(d,c) = 1$. Applying Bezout's identity to $d,c$ we find two integers $z,w$ such that
$$
1 = dz + cw = a(xz) + b(yz) + cw
$$

Comment: thank you very much,but this is actually from a problem, and it seem that many people (some I know) come up with this way, but they can not provide a math proof, you may see the comment in:http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/SRM+664#BearPlaysDiv2

Comment: Actually, I cannot see that comment because a login is required. Anyway, what I wrote above is indeed a proof. Is there something I should clarify?